# Idempotent ideal in ring of continuous functions

Tags: gn.general-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

Is there any equivalence conditions under which an ideal $I$ in ring of continuous functions be be an idempotent ideal?

Comment: Not an answer - truly a comment - but perhaps this can add a shred of context: It is easy to find all the idempotent *elements* in the ring of continuous functions: the two constant functions, $0$ and $1$ (proof: intermediate value theorem). In a Noetherian ring, every idempotent ideal is generated by an idempotent element; unfortunately, this fact is not of direct use here: the ring of continuous functions is *not* Noetherian. Hence the question at hand may arise.

Comment: An interesting idempotent ideal is for example the ideal of all functions that vanish at $0$ and that go faster to $0$ than any polynomial.

Comment: Continuous functions on what space? If your space is totally disconnected there can be lots of idempotents